# How to connect five points in curve

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to connect five points in curve. 
This is my current code, but it does not look like in good shape:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}
\newcommand{\cL}{\mathcal L}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[very thick,<->] (-0.5,0) -- (11.0,0);%node[anchor=north west] {$x$};
    \coordinate (A1) at (1,1);
    \coordinate (A3) at (3,1.5);
    \coordinate (A5) at (5,1.9);
    \coordinate (A7) at (7,1.5);
    \coordinate (A9) at (9,1);
    \foreach \coor/\formula in {A1/{u1},A3/{u2},A5/{u3},A7/{u4},A9/{u5}} {
      \fill (\coor) circle (2pt);
      \node[below right, inner xsep=-1ex] at (\coor) {$\formula$};
      %\node[above] at (A1) {$u$};
    \draw (A1) to[in=190] (A3) to[out=10, in=210] (A5);
    \draw [out=-10](A5) to[in=200] (A7) to[ out=-10,in=200] (A9);
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A quick hint: If you highlight lines of LaTeX code and indent them by four spaces -- easily done by clicking on the `{}` "button" above the editing window -- the code will be pretty-printed by the site's software. A suggestion/request: don't just post a code snippet, but rather a self-contained LaTeX program that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` that loads all relevant packages. Doing so frees up valuable time for anyone who might want to contribute a solution.

Comment: Do you want to draw a parabola with 5 points on it? Can you hand draw the intended out put and post it?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that you want to connect your points with a smooth curve, do it like so:

```
\documentclass[border = 10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[very thick,<->] (-0.5,0) -- (11.0,0);
   \coordinate (A1) at (1,1);
   \coordinate (A3) at (3,1.5);
   \coordinate (A5) at (5,1.9);
   \coordinate (A7) at (7,1.5);
   \coordinate (A9) at (9,1);
   \foreach \coor/\formula in {A1/{u1},A3/{u2},A5/{u3},A7/{u4},A9/{u5}} {
     \fill (\coor) circle (2pt)
       node[below right, inner xsep=-1ex] {$\formula$};
    }
    \draw[smooth] plot coordinates{(A1) (A3) (A5) (A7) (A9)};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: A smooth curve]

There's more in section 22.8 of the TikZ 3.0.0 manual.